# Printing Activereports page programmatically

Tags: winforms, activereports

How do you print a specific page from the activereports report Windows viewer control programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

```
 viewer.Document.Printer.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 2;
 viewer.Document.Printer.PrinterSettings.ToPage = 4;
 viewer.Document.Print(false, true);
```

You can find more information about programatically setting printer options at http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports6_start.html?ActiveReports.Document~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.Printer.html

Hope this helps!

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity
```